# How to Create fancy dmg installer on MAC OS X 10.6?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm trying to make fancy DMG installer, that has background, and link to Applicaitons.

I'm aware of this question, and ansewrs. But all of them are pretty old tutorials I guess.

Like this one http://www.ploem.be/blog/?page%5Fid=26 /

When I am trying to go to View ->Show View Options- I don't see anything that let's me to choose background, and for this Windows only options.

If you have idea where to find tutorials that will work on 10.6 , or 10.7 for creating installer with background. I will really appreciate it.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been using third-party tool for this task for years and really happy with it. [DMG Canvas](http://www.araelium.com/dmgcanvas/) - it has a built-in console utility that makes it possible to use the tool with my build scripts. Check it out, it might solve your problems too.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use a third-party tool: http://web.media.mit.edu/~guy/misc/dmg-howto.html

Additionally, you can add a background to a Finder window by clicking "View" -> "Show View Options", but only when in Icon view, as far as I know.